# Kafka and mult-iline (two by two lines) csv file: can Kafka handle it to gather each couple of lines in a single message?

Tags: java, csv, apache-kafka, multiline

I want to analyze my bathroom scale measurements, exportable in `csv`.
But they cannot be exploited immediately.

```
Durée,Poids,Variation,IMC,Masse grasse,Masse musculaire squelettique,Masse osseuse,Masse hydrique,
" 14 Fév. 2022",
06:37,72.1 kg,0.3 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
" 13 Fév. 2022",
06:48,72.4 kg,0.2 kg,22.9,25.4 %,29.8 kg,3.6 kg,54.4 %,
```

- its records ends with a comma,
- the date is on the first line, while other data for that day is on the second line,
- they are units or percentile signs inside the cells.

**Cleanings are needed, and I would like to use *Kafka* for that.**
I never used *Kafka* before: it will read a `csv` file, yes, but can it handle the case where that `csv` is a multi-line one?

A way that it can offer me core messages with this content, for beginning:

```
" 14 Fév. 2022","06:37","72.1 kg","0.3 kg","22.8","26.3 %","29.7 kg","3.5 kg","53.8 %"
" 13 Fév. 2022","06:48","72.4 kg","0.2 kg","22.9","25.4 %","29.8 kg","3.6 kg","54.4 %"
```

with fields of `String` type named :
"Durée", "Poids", "Variation", "IMC", "Masse grasse", "Masse musculaire squelettique", "Masse osseuse", "Masse hydrique".

This crude shape would allow me to start a more precise treatment.

**What do you suggest me to do through *Kafka*?**
If this maneuver looks too tricky, I can read that `csv` file by a small *Java* program, treat roughly its worse problems, and send the corrected content to *Kafka* then.

But I would enjoy more handling the whole `csv` content entirely by *Kafka*.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't care about data formats. You'll need to parse the file on your own (in any language, not necessarily Java), outside of Kafka, then build a serializable record that can be produced.

You'd have similar issues with a simple database, and I'm not sure I see the need for Kafka here

Comment: The goal is to have a unique handler, Kafka, to neutralize all data asperities. This is an exercise for myself to learn Kafka for this purpose, of course, but after it will have implications on many csv file handling that comes in various conditions from different sources. _Kafka_, I think, do care about data format and types. How would it sort or partition your messages by date or integer, else, if you asking so, if it cannot recognize a date or integer, and consider everything like a string?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't care. Your parsers care. You define serializers before data ever reaches a broker. It doesn't sort and all stored types are binary. Partitioning is done by hashing of byte arrays. If you want sorting, by date, use a database